# Python _tkinter.TclError: bad screen distance "0.5" using Turtle module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-turtle

I'm a turtle's beginner and I wrote a little program (`file.py`) who draws something.
But when I call the file with an `import` statement from another file (`theotherfile.py`. Note that it use tkinter), I have this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jeandubois\Documents\GitHub\myproject\theotherfile.py", line 443, in <module>
    import theotherfile
  File "C:\Users\jeandubois\Documents\GitHub\myproject\file.py", line 10, in <module>
    turtle1 = turtle.Turtle()
  File "C:\Users\jeandubois\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\turtle.py", line 3813, in __init__
    Turtle._screen = Screen()
  File "C:\Users\jeandubois\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\turtle.py", line 3663, in Screen
    Turtle._screen = _Screen()
  File "C:\Users\jeandubois\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\turtle.py", line 3689, in __init__
    self._root.setupcanvas(width, height, canvwidth, canvheight)
  File "C:\Users\jeandubois\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\turtle.py", line 438, in setupcanvas
    self._canvas = ScrolledCanvas(self, width, height, cwidth, cheight)
  File "C:\Users\jeandubois\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\turtle.py", line 343, in __init__
    self._canvas = TK.Canvas(master, width=width, height=height,
  File "C:\Users\jeandubois\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2685, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'canvas', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Users\jeandubois\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2569, in __init__
    self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: bad screen distance "0.5"
```

My code :

```
# file.py
import tkinter
root = tkinter.Tk()
[some awesome code]
root.mainloop()
# when closing root:
import theotherfile
```

```
# theotherfile.py
import turtle
turtle1 = turtle.Turtle()
turtle2 = turtle.Turtle()
turtle3 = turtle.Turtle()

turtle1.speed(100)
turtle2.speed(100)
turtle3.speed(100)

turtle1.width(5)
turtle2.width(5)
turtle3.width(5)

turtle1.color(choice(colors))
turtle2.color(choice(colors))
turtle3.color(choice(colors))

turtle1.up()
turtle2.up()
turtle3.up()
turtle1.goto(-100, -100)
turtle2.goto(0, -100)
turtle3.goto(-50, -13.4)
turtle1.down()
turtle2.down()
turtle3.down()

a = 100
for loop in range(2):
    for loop2 in range(3):
        turtle1.forward(a)
        turtle1.left(120)
        turtle2.forward(a)
        turtle2.left(120)
        turtle3.forward(a)
        turtle3.left(120)
        turtle1.color(choice(colors))
        turtle2.color(choice(colors))
        turtle3.color(choice(colors))
    a = 50

turtle1.forward(50)
turtle2.forward(50)
turtle3.forward(50)

for loop in range(5):
    turtle1.forward(a)
    turtle1.left(120)
    turtle2.forward(a)
    turtle2.left(120)
    turtle3.forward(a)
    turtle3.left(120)
    turtle1.color(choice(colors))
    turtle2.color(choice(colors))
    turtle3.color(choice(colors))

turtle1.right(60)
turtle2.right(60)
turtle3.right(60)
turtle1.forward(50)
turtle2.forward(50)
turtle3.forward(50)

turtle1.up()
turtle2.up()
turtle3.up()

turtle1.hideturtle()
turtle2.hideturtle()
turtle3.hideturtle()

turtle.mainloop()
```

I use Python 3.9.0 .

Can someone help me please ?

Comment: Please include your code so I can help.

Comment: It's done :-) !

Comment: I ran the code, but other than needing to remove the `[some awesome code]`line, there isn't an error.

Comment: In the awesome code, I just use a tkinter Frame, some Labels, OptionMenus, Buttons and Menus.
I use too the `pip` module (to make some modules updates like PyGame).
I don't see any error either...

Comment: Other than missing `from random import choice` and `colors = ["blue", "red"]`, this works fine for me. What are your environment details?